# UNABLE TO RETRIEVE THE LIST OF DATABASES MySQL connection Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm unable to retrieve the list of databases on MySql on Visual Studio 2017

Here is the problem screenshot:

[image: Problem in Visual Studio 2017]
Does someone have somo information about this problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you waited for the list of databases to load. Instead, just locate the database manually, or drag and drop from the source.